# RuntimeException: Error receiving broadcast Intent

Tags: java, android, usb

I'm getting this error while accessing fingerprint this errorr comes from SDK

```java
    public void OpenDevice() {
        this.isReceive = false;
        isSetSensorOption = false;
        isGetSensorSetting = false;
        this.mManager = (UsbManager)this.activity.getSystemService("usb");
        Map<String, UsbDevice> deviceList = this.mManager.getDeviceList();
        if (deviceList.size() == 0) {
            this.capture_callback.OnDisConnected();
        } else {
            Iterator<UsbDevice> deviceIterator = deviceList.values().iterator();

            while(deviceIterator.hasNext()) {
                UsbDevice device = (UsbDevice)deviceIterator.next();
                Log.e(TAG, "device.getVendorId():" + device.getVendorId());
                Log.e(TAG, "device.getProductId():" + device.getProductId());
                if (device.getVendorId() == 2694) {
                    if (device.getProductId() == 1538 || device.getProductId() == 1616 || device.getProductId() == 256) {
                        CURRENT_PRODUCT_ID = device.getProductId();
                        this.mPermissionIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this.activity, 0, new Intent("com.android.example.USB_PERMISSION"), 0);
                        this.mManager.requestPermission(device, this.mPermissionIntent);
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

This code from AndroidNBioBSPJNI.jar

While accessing i'm gettting that error and screen blank and goes back to previous activity

> E  FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> Process: com.bosco.ivdpshg, PID: 16585
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Error receiving broadcast Intent {
> act=com.android.example.USB_PERMISSION flg=0x10 (has extras) } in
> com.nitgen.SDK.AndroidBSP.NBioBSPJNI$1@cc2ad00
> at
> android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.lambda$getRunnable$0$LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args(LoadedApk.java:1676)
> at
> android.app.-$$Lambda$LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args$_BumDX2UKsnxLVrE6UJsJZkotuA.run(Unknown
> Source:2)
> at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:246)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8653)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> at
> com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:602)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1130)
> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual
> method 'android.hardware.usb.UsbDeviceConnection
> android.hardware.usb.UsbManager.openDevice(android.hardware.usb.UsbDevice)'
> on a null object reference
> at
> com.nitgen.SDK.AndroidBSP.NBioBSPJNI.setInterface(NBioBSPJNI.java:207)
> at com.nitgen.SDK.AndroidBSP.NBioBSPJNI.access$2(NBioBSPJNI.java:196)
> at
> com.nitgen.SDK.AndroidBSP.NBioBSPJNI$1.onReceive(NBioBSPJNI.java:112)
> at
> android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.lambda$getRunnable$0$LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args(LoadedApk.java:1666)
> at
> android.app.-$$Lambda$LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args$_BumDX2UKsnxLVrE6UJsJZkotuA.run(Unknown
> Source:2) 
> at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938) 
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:246) 
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8653) 
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
> at
> com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:602) 
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1130) 
> 2024-02-24 11:44:42.389 16585-16585 FirebaseCrashlytics
> com.bosco.ivdpshg                    E  Cannot send reports. Timed out
> while fetching settings.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.